# Where is the Typesense document ID

Tags: typesense

I am starting to learn to use Typesense, and I successfully import it from my Firestore. When I want to delete a document from dashboard, it asked the document id.

I know the document id is document id from my firestore collection, since I am not put id field explicitly. But, I can see any document id information from the Typesense dashboard.

Where can I easily find my document id?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I tested and this worked for me:
If you explicitly index the id in the collection schema, you can see the id in the dashboard (and it will be the same as the firestore id).
If you don't index it, the id will be 0 for the first document; 1 for the second, and so on...
Hope i could help

Comment: No, it is not shown in the dashboard even I index the ID explicitly. I think the only way to get the ID is get the documents using API and get the ID by using objectID value. No way to do it in the dashboard.

Comment: Did you explicitly defined the index  id in the collection schema? Like so:
    {
      "facet": false,
      "index": true,
      "name": "id",
      "optional": false,
      "type": "string"
    },

Comment: In this question context, I didnt. I am using firestore importer to import collection from firestore.

Comment: Just stumbled on this question. I've pushed out an update to the Typesense Dashboard, so that it shows the Document ID regardless of whether it is mentioned in the schema or not.

Answer (score 0):

I always define or before putting it in the collection

sample:

```
user = {
  id: v4(),
  ...etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a trigger for a particular collection, it's necessary to specify the collection ID. Here's an example of the code I've implemented:

```
    import { logger } from "firebase-functions/v2";
    import { onDocumentWritten } from "firebase-functions/v2/firestore";
    import { typesense } from "../utils/typesense";

    // Load environment variables
    const {
      TYPESENSE_KEY,
      COLLECTION,
      COLLECTION_DOCUMENT_PATH,
    } = process.env;

    export const syncTypesenseOnOffsiteNotificationInsert = onDocumentWritten(
      {
        secrets: [TYPESENSE_KEY],
        document: COLLECTION_DOCUMENT_PATH || "collectionName/{docId}",
        maxInstances: 5,
        concurrency: 500,
        retry: true,
        cpu: 2,
        timeoutSeconds: 180,
      },
      async (event) => {
        if (!event.data?.after || !event.data.after.data()) {
          return;
        }

        try {
          if (event.data.before && event.data.before.isEqual(event.data.after)) {
            // Before and after documents match, just return; no need to be in a loop!
            return;
          }

          const offsiteNotification = event.data?.after.data();

          // Additional checks and processing for offsite document can be added here

          logger.info(`Updating ${event.data.after.id}`);

          await typesense
            .collections(COLLECTION || "collectionName")
            .documents()
            .upsert({
              ...collectionName,
              id: event.data.after.id,
              createdAt: collectionName?.createdAt?._seconds,
            });

          logger.info("We are done");
          return;
        } catch (error) {
          logger.error("We encountered an error");
          logger.error(error);
          throw Error("We failed");
        }
      }
    );
```

When creating a trigger for a particular collection, it's necessary to specify the collection ID. Here's an example of the code I've implemented: